# How to populate html input from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am not quite sure how to attack this, basically I have two html fields in my aspx page:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="text" name="lname"/>
```

Now i would like to populate them from the server side when the page loads based on some data collected from the database, basically this data is stored in two properties

```
public string FirstName { get; set;}
public string LastName {get; set;}
```

How can I pass the value from such properties into the html inputs On_Load ?

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, assuming Webforms:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<%:FirstName%>" />
<input type="text" name="lname" value="<%:LastName%>" />
```

If using .NET before 4.0, replace the `<%:` with `<%=`.

Another option is to change the input types to be `runat="server"` and assigning the values directly on the server side.

Comment: You may want to check that second input ;)

Comment: @Oded Very useful. I never knew about using "<:" over "<%=". +1!

Comment: @Oded, is there a difference between using `<@:` and `<@=`?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - Yes. `<%:` is `<%=` with `Html.Encode` included. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively add `runat="server"` to your elements, then you could do something like

```
fname.Value = FirstName;
lname.Value = LastName;
```

Comment: Is that right? If it was a server side control you wouldn't need to FindControl, use could access it directly.

Comment: True. But `FindControl` doesn't work on client side controls. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) - "Searches the current naming container for a **server control** with the specified id parameter."

Answer (score 0):

The info I was looking for was like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    address.Value = Request.QueryString["lat"];
    address1.Value = Request.QueryString["long"];
}
```

takes values from the URL string and puts them in an HTML input="text"

http://localhost:64375/Map.aspx?lat=detroit&long=windsor

```
 Enter Address A: <input runat="server" name="address" id="address" type="text" />
 Enter Address B: <input runat="server" name="address1" id="address1" type="text" />
```

thanks Ash and Oded for the combined answer